# Send email from Google Spreadsheet omitting the commas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

All,

I use a similar script to the below to send emails from a google spreadsheet:

```
// Sends an email when .......
function emailInfoRequired(row) { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var subject = "Info Needed: " + sheet.getRange("F19").getValues();
  var recipients = "email@email.com"
  var message = "<HTML><BODY>" 
    + "<P>" + sheet.getRange("K1").getValues()
    + "<BR>" + sheet.getRange("K2").getValues()
    + "</HTML></BODY>"; 
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
}
```

What i would like to do is instead of using single cells,i want to include a range such as:  sheet.getRange("K2:N2").getValues()

The problem is, when i do this, the email body has a comma between every cell within that range making the email not make any sense plus look ugly.  I tried formatting the cells as plain text but that didnt help.  Is there a way to send the email of a range and not show the commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could even make it more elegant by using a html table like this :

```
// Sends an email when .......
function emailInfoRequired(row) { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var subject = "Info Needed: " + sheet.getRange("F19").getValues();
  var recipients = "testmail@gmail.com"
  var data = sheet.getRange('A2:C25').getValues();// define your range here
  var message = '<HTML><BODY><table style="background-color:lightblue;border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1 cellpadding = 5><tr>';// change eventually the color here
  for (var row=0;row<data.length;++row){
    for(var col = 0;col<data[0].length;++col){
      message += '<td>'+data[row][col]+'</td>';
    }
    message += '</tr><tr>';
  }
    message += '</tr></table></body></HTML>';
   MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
}
```

Illustration example :

[image]

Comment: This worked great keeping everything in the same row.  I will definately hang onto that code for future use.  With this project, I am basically trying to concatenate the data along each row and display it as a single value in the email.  Making it so that 1 row = 1 line of text in the email.

Comment: It gives 1 row per SS row and 1 column per SS column in a table. I guess I didn't understand clearly what you needed.

Comment: After looking at my data some more, I can definitely work with what you have.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, note there was a small typo in the code, there shouldn't be a </td> tag in the second loop... it does not create any issue but it's not "academic" so better to remove it. I edit the code, this version is ok.

Answer (score 1):

`Range.getValues()` returns a 2D array and a string representation of this 2D array is printed in your email. Depending on how you want to show it in your email, you have to process each element individually. Something like...

```
function emailInfoRequired(row) { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var subject = "Info Needed: " + sheet.getRange("F19").getValues();
  var recipients = "email@email.com"
  var values = sheet.getRange("K2:N2").getValues();
  var message = "<HTML><BODY>" ;
  for (var row = 0 ; row < values.length ; row++){
    message +=  "<P>" ;
    for (var col= 0 ; col < values[row].length ; col++){
      message +=  "<BR>" + values[row][col];
    }
  }
  message  += "</HTML></BODY>"; 
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
}
```

Comment: Wow, i did not realize it would be that complex.  My code consists of 35+/- rows in the email.  Would i have to repeat that code for every row and give a unique name for each row? Like var values1 = ....var values2 = .....var values3 =.......etc.

Comment: I could edit the spreadsheet and put all the data in a range similar to "K2:N40".  If i did that, would that work with the code you have above?

Comment: Have you tried the code I provided ? Noticed the for loop ? You don't have to have one variable for each row. As an aside, if any programming language made you do that, that would be a worthless one

Comment: I did try it.  It put every cell in that range on a new line.  I want to retain the rows of the spreadsheet with rows in the email.