# Google Apps Script [Email Send]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there a way to make the output of 'message' in the email neater?
Right now, it's just 1 line of long data sent to the user. I tried using `<br>` but it didnt seem to work.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  setUpCalendar_(data, range);
  var message = "";
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var subject = "Compiled List for " + row[0];

    message += row[0] + row[1] + row[2] + row[3]; 

  }
  MailApp.sendEmail("emailgoeshere", subject, message);
}
```

Comment: see this other similar post for an example :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382678/send-email-from-google-spreadsheet-omitting-the-commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, this has already been explained a few times...

below is an example that sends data in text format AND in html format so that recipients that reject html content will still see something readable ;-)

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  setUpCalendar_(data, range);
  var txt = "";
  var html = '<table style="background-color:lightblue;border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1 cellpadding = 5><tr>'
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var subject = "Compiled List for " + row[0];
    txt += row[0] +' - '+ row[1]  +' - '+ row[2]  +' - '+ row[3]+'\n'; 
    html+= '<td>'+row[0] +'</td><td>'+ row[1]  +'</td><td>'+ row[2]  +'</td><td>'+ row[3] +'</td></tr><tr>'; 
  }
  html += '</tr></table>';
  MailApp.sendEmail('an email adress', subject, txt,{'htmlBody':html});
}
```

Change the background color to your taste

Answer (score 0):

Try using \n to start a new line